# Why is $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)$ not $3x^2 + 3x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

In 3Blue1Brown's ['The Essence of Calculus'](https://youtu.be/S0_qX4VJhMQ?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&t=281) chapter 3 he shows a geometric analogy of why the derivative of $f(x)=x^3$ is $3x^2$.

[image: Video screenshot]

I understand why we can ignore the tiny cube in the corner. But why do we also ignore the three lines along the edges of the cube? Each has a volume of $x$ as $dx$ approaches zero.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Shortly, because the edges are of "second order" with respect to the "small" $dx$. While the volume of the sides is $3x^2\,dx$, the volume of the edges is $3x\,dx^2$,where $dx$ is *squared*. On the other hand, the essence of taking the derivative is to approximate the growth of the function "near" a point by a *linear* function of $dx$. The edges make a small *quadratic* correction. To do more precise approximations (quadratic, cubic etc.) you use Taylor's polynomial.

Comment: The notation $\frac{df}{dx}(x^3)$ in the title is incorrect. It should be $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)$.

Comment: Personally I don't think this geometric picture is a very good way to think about derivatives; if you ever do differential geometry in the future it has the potential to do more harm than good.

Comment: Notice that $(x+\mathrm{d}x)^3=x^3+3x^2\,\mathrm{d}x+3x\,\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}x^3.$ The coefficient of $\mathrm{d}x$ is equal to the derivative. The coefficient of $\mathrm{d}x^2$ is equal to half the second derivative.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Because, for me, it's hard to understand what it means to approximate. $3x\,dx^2$ is not zero, so why to ignore it even if it becomes negligibly small?

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data If this analogy of the cube is false, is there a better way to visualise it?

Comment: @domizai The accepted answer approaches it better. The analogy is not false: it's a perfectly appropriate analogy, it's just that it doesn't fully encapsulate the purely mathematical ideas behind the derivative. It's better (and more modern) to think of it in terms of limits rather than infinitesimals. If you've understood that, then by all means employ the volume, but make sure you've got the fundamentals right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's replace the infinitesimal $\mathrm dx$ with a finite $h\in\Bbb R^+$, so$$f(x+h)-f(x)=3x^2h+3xh^2+h^3.$$(One could adopt axioms about powers of $\mathrm dx$ that let me work with it instead of $h$, but right now it's not worth the hassle.) We define$$f^\prime(x):=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\left(3x^2+3xh+h^2\right)=3x^2.$$The $h\to0$ limit doesn't just delete the numerator's fastest-shrinking term $h^3$, i.e. the one with the highest power of $h$. It deletes every term that shrinks faster than the denominator $h$.

The geometric insight is that, for small $h$, the strips along three of the cube's edges have much less volume than the squares covering three of its faces, even if the volume at one vertex is much smaller still. When taking the first derivative, the highest-order correction (i.e. largest piece added) wins.

Comment: This makes much more sense to me. I guess the geometric analogy did more harm than good.

Answer (score 3):

$$d(x^3)=(x+d\!x)^3-x^3=3x^2d\!x+3xd\!x^2+d\!x^3$$
where $\!x$ is one symbol name.
Therefore
$$\frac{d}{d\!x}(x^3)=3x^2+3xd\!x+d\!x^2$$
and further
$$\frac{d}{d\!x}(x^3)=3x^2$$
if we ignore the two infinitesimal summands.

Answer (score 2):

Take a cube of $1$ meter size. Table another one of $1.01$ meter. The new volume is
$$(1.01)^3=1.030301000$$ So
$$\frac{(1.01)^3 -(1.00)^3} {0.01 }=3.0301$$ Now doing it for a cube of $1.001$
$$\frac{(1.001)^3 -(1.000)^3} {0.001 }=3.003001$$